# Read data from firebase for login page in swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to make an authentication data when user log in.

Here is my code:

```
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("data")

    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let score = value?["data"] as? String ?? ""


        if userPhone == score{
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSuccessSegue", sender: nil)
        }else{

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginButtonSegue", sender: nil)

        }

    })
```

And this is my Json:

```
{
  "data" : {
    "2" : 2,
    "-LAHu2g4g2S9UBRUSzYy" : "ada",
    "-LAHuvLqM-14e4tC39fr" : "0818088325",
    "-LAIU21b5n9JKgyi9Yct" : "2",
    "asd" : "asd"
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: i cant read the data from firebase

Comment: What's the problem with reading the data? E.g.: if you run the code under the XCode debugger and set a breakpoint on `let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary`, does it get hit?

Answer (score 0):

Replace .childAdded with .value. It should work.

```
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
    let score = value?["data"] as? String ?? ""
    }
```